# xml as <option type="x">y</option>

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I have a table with attributes

```
prodid  type    val
1       colour  red
1       size    large
2       colour  blue
```

I have as part of a larger query making a xml structure:

```
(SELECT type "@type",val  from t_prodattr pa where pa.prodid=product.id 
 FOR xml path('attribute'), root('attributes'), type),
```

Giving

```
 <attributes>
    <attribute type="colour">
      <val>red</val>
    </attribute>
    <attribute type="size">
      <val>small</val>
    </attribute>
  </attributes>
```

I'd like xml to be

```
<attributes>
    <attribute type="colour">red</attribute>
    <attribute type="size">small</attribute>
</attributes>
```

or even

```
<attributes>
    <colour>red</colour>
    <size>small</size>
</attributes>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'*'` as an alias for `val`.

```
SELECT type '@type',
       val as '*'  
from ...
```

[Columns with a Name Specified as a Wildcard Character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500154.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Update:

If you want the element names from the `type` column you have to build the XML partly by concatenating strings.

```
declare @T table
(
  prodid int,
  type varchar(10),
  val varchar(10)
);

insert into @T values
(1,       'colour',  'red  '),
(1,       'size',    'la&ge'),
(2,       'colour',  'blue ');

select cast('<'+T.type+'>'+(select T.val as '*' for xml path(''))+'</'+T.type+'>' as xml)
from @T as T
for xml path(''), root('attributes'), type
```

Result:

```
<attributes>
  <colour>red  </colour>
  <size>la&amp;ge</size>
  <colour>blue </colour>
</attributes>
```

This part `(select T.val as '*' for xml path(''))` is there to take care of creating entities for XML special characters like `&<>`.

Comment: All answers good, this one selected because it answers both options

Answer (score 1):

**Schema**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
  (
          [type]    VARCHAR(10) ,
          Val VARCHAR(10)
  )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'colour', 'red' ),
        ( 'size', 'large' ),
        ( 'colours', 'blue' )
```

**Query**

```
SELECT  type "@type" ,
        Val AS '*'
FROM    @t
FOR     XML PATH('attribute') ,
            ROOT('attributes') ,
            TYPE;
```

**Output**

```
<attributes>
  <attribute type="colour">red</attribute>
  <attribute type="size">large</attribute>
  <attribute type="colours">blue</attribute>
</attributes>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    prodid INT,
    [type] VARCHAR(50),
    val VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
    (1, 'colour', 'red'),
    (1, 'size', 'large'),
    (2, 'colour', 'blue')

SELECT
    (
        SELECT [@type] = [type], [text()] = val
        FROM @t t2
        WHERE t2.prodid = t1.prodid
        FOR XML PATH('attribute'), root('attributes'), TYPE
    )
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT prodid
    FROM @t
) t1
FOR XML PATH('')
```

results -

```
<attributes>
  <attribute type="colour">red</attribute>
  <attribute type="size">large</attribute>
</attributes>
<attributes>
  <attribute type="colour">blue</attribute>
</attributes>
```